# Should we allow "best of" lists as community wiki?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I asked this question [What is your favorite data visualization blog?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103/what-is-your-favorite-data-visualization-blog) which is essentially just allowing people to list and rank their favorites.  Should this be allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Taking Stack Overflow as our model I think we should.

But there are some caveats we need to think about.

There is an issue with keeping the resources so listed up to date and making sure they're relevant, does this fall to the OP, a Moderator, each respondent?

If I'm using such a list should I edit it if things become out of date, or aren't particularly useful. Maybe I should add a comment next to a list.

If the post is CW do we want the links to be added to the Original Post or first answer (in the way that meta stackexchange contains a list of stack exchange sites [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites))?

Or do we want individual answers one per post so that they can be voted up by usefulness etc?

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, as these lists are very valuable resources. A perfect example is your answer on [statistical datasets.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252144/datasets-for-running-statistical-analysis-on)

Answer (score 0):

Absoulutely! on the new [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) and [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) sites I found some really neat stuff on "Best Of" lists.  Making them community wikis is highly appropriate.